# How to persist local CSS change to server record?

Tags: javascript, css, meteor

I have a client method that grays out a rendered document in the DOM by adding a class whose opacity is set to 0.4:

```
   'click .detailCheckbox': function(ev){
    var detail = $(ev.target).parent();

    if(!detail.hasClass('toggle')){
        detail.addClass('toggle');  
    } else {
        detail.removeClass('toggle');
    }

}
```

When I reload the page, though, the DOM element is no longer grayed out, because I never updated the document on the server.

Am I going to have to get super creative here, or am I missing a simple way to solve this?

Comment: You could either use AJAX to update the server, or use a cookie or localStorage to save the state on the client.

Comment: You don't want to update the document on the server, because that will affect all users. You would need to save the state for the user in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a new field in the model, which is set (or unset) to the class name that has opacity 0.4

Here is the Meteor method insert method that contains the field `checkboxStatus`

```
addDetail: function(detailFormData){
    if(! Meteor.userId()){
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
    }

    detailsCollection.insert({
        detail: detailFormData.detail,
        parentId: detailFormData.parentId,
        checkboxStatus: detailFormData.checkboxStatus  
    });
}
```

I call it on the clicking of the checkbox:

```
'click .detailCheckbox': function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    Meteor.call('setToggle', this._id);
}
```

And the `setToggle` Meteor method checks the toggle status, and then updates the document accordingly

```
setToggle: function(detailId){
    var checked_detail = detailsCollection.findOne({_id: detailId});

    if(checked_detail.checkboxStatus != 'toggle'){
        detailsCollection.update(detailId, {
            $set: {checkboxStatus: 'toggle'}
        });
    } else {
        detailsCollection.update(detailId, {
            $set: {checkboxStatus: 'untoggle'}
        });
    }

}
```

Which is then called by a template helper method

```
checkboxStatus: function(){
    var checked_detail = detailsCollection.findOne({_id: this._id});
    return checked_detail.checkboxStatus;
}
```

whose value is returned in the class tag of the template item itself

`<li id={{_id}} class="detailViewEntry {{checkboxStatus}}">`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [meteor-persistent-session package](https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session/).

```
Session.setPersistent(key, value) //store a persistent session variable (persistent)
```

For example.

```
 if(!detail.hasClass('toggle')){
        detail.addClass('toggle');
        Session.setPersistent('opacity',0.4)  
    } else {
        detail.removeClass('toggle');
        Session.clear('opacity')
    }
```